# about deprecated method ParquetFileReader.readFooter

Tags: hadoop, parquet

I see `ParquetFileReader.readFooter` was deprecated in `parquet-hadoop-1.11.0.jar`. What class or which method should be used instead？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on code comments, you should use [`ParquetFileReader#open(InputFile, ParquetReadOptions)`](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/parquet-1.10.x/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetFileReader.java#L586).

```
  /**
   * Reads the meta data block in the footer of the file
   * @param configuration a configuration
   * @param file the parquet File
   * @return the metadata blocks in the footer
   * @throws IOException if an error occurs while reading the file
   * @deprecated will be removed in 2.0.0;
   *             use {@link ParquetFileReader#open(InputFile, ParquetReadOptions)}
   */
  @Deprecated
  public static final ParquetMetadata readFooter(Configuration configuration, Path file) throws IOException {
```

Comment: which make it rather complicated to construct a metadata only read.